# Formulas VBA com @

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Quando escreve a formula de uma função pelo VBA, e adiciono alguma formula do excel, ele incrementa um @ antes da fórmula automaticamente. Por exemplo:

Selection = "=SOMA(A1)"

Na barra de fórmulas da planilha fica =@SOMA(A1) e não executa. Alguém sabe como tirar este @ automático? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O Selection é um objeto genérico que pode possuir vários tipos. No seu caso ele é um *Range*, que representa uma célula. Para setar fórmulas usando o Selection, faça:

```
Selection.FormulaLocal = "=SOMA(A1)"
```

*FormulaLocal* é usada para transformar a Soma (Português) em Sum (Inglês)
Para ver o que o Selection representa, digite na Verificação imediatada (Ctrl+G no VBA):

```
?Typename(Selection)
```

Isso vai retornar o que o Selection é naquele momento.
Para aprender mais sobre aquele objeto, no seu caso o Range, Aperte F2 e pesquise por Range. Lá terá muitas informações.